# rpmbuild does not create rpm but gives no warning. How to debug?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am creating my own rpms. I have a spec file that builds without problem on opensuse 12.1 and 13.1 environments. It is a noarch rpm containing only bash scripts. I clone the repository as is on a opensuse 12.3 environment and there rpmbuild runs without (apparent) problem, but does not produce the final rpm. I tried running with -vv option, but that doesn't bring me any further. Any ideas on how to get to the root of this problem?

this is my rpmbuild command:

```
rpmbuild -vv -ba myrpm.spec
```

and its (relevant)

```
...
Requires(postun): /bin/sh
Requires: /bin/bash
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/chris/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/myrpm-1.0.0-0.i386
Wrote: /home/chris/rpmbuild/SRPMS/myrpm-1.0.0-0.src.rpm
```

as I said before, on the other systems I get the exact same output except for the line that he wrote the rpm:

```
Wrote: /home/chris/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/myrpm-1.0.0-0.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, but I have no real answer. I have tried for at least 5 times with no change. Then I switched to super user to check for an update of rpmbuild (none available). Disconnected from super user again, and now the command worked... strange!

Comment: Had a similar experience, the -vv option only wasted more time.  Deleted the rpm build directors and started again with the same SPEC files at it worked.